# What will be the Gain if the resistor value tends to infinity?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier

[image]

Given the circuit above, I need to find the expression for gain if the r_pi tends to infinity.

[image]

my question is will v_pi still be v_in?

Comment: ask yourself what is \$g_m\cdot V_{\pi}\$.

Comment: voltage controlled current source. will the v_pi still be v_in ? since in my opinion there will be the v_in across those r_pi terminals

Comment: This question appears to be homework. **Complete answers to homework are off-topic**, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, \$v_{\pi}\$ will still be equal to \$v_{in}\$.

For a more interesting question, consider the case where the input source is not an ideal voltage source, but a non-ideal source with a non-zero Thevenin resistance.

Now, the input voltage seen by your amplifier is the output of the divider formed by the source resistance (call it \$R_s\$) and \$r_\pi\$. Then increasing \$r_\pi\$ tends to make the input seen by the amplifier closer to the source voltage (i.e. reduces the effect of \$R_s\$). Taking \$r_\pi\to\infty\$ results in an ideal amplifier where the signal source's output resistance doesn't affect the gain.